# How do i print word after regex but not a similar word?

Tags: sed, awk, duplicates

I want an awk or sed command to print the word after regexp.

I want to find the WORD after a WORD but not the WORD that looks similar.

The file looks like this:

```
 somethingsomething
 X-Windows-Icon=xournal
 somethingsomething
 Icon=xournal
 somethingsomething
 somethingsomething
```

I want "xournal" from the one that say "Icon=xournal". This is how far i have come until now. I have tried an AWK string too but it was also unsuccessful.

```
cat "${file}" | grep 'Icon=' | sed 's/.*Icon=//' >> /tmp/text.txt
```

But i get both so the text file gives two xournal which i don't want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `^` to anchor the pattern at the beginning of the line. And you can even do the grepping directly within sed:

```
sed -n '/^Icon=/ { s/.*=//; p; }' "$file" >> /tmp/text.txt
```

You could also use awk, which I think reads a little better. Using `=` as the field separator, if field 1 is `Icon` then print field 2:

```
awk -F= '$1=="Icon" {print $2}' "$file" >> /tmp/text.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful even though Perl is not one of the tags.
In case if you are interested in Perl this small program will do the task for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

while(<>)
{
    if(/Icon\=/i)
    {
        print $';
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>io.pl new2.txt
xournal
xournal
```

explanation:

- `while (<>)` takes the input data from the file given as an argument on the command line while executing.
- `(/Icon\=/i)` is the regex used in the `if` condition.
- `$'` will print the part of the line after the regex.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
sed -n 's/^Icon=//p' file
```