# Use a RegEx expression for PayPal output

Tags: regex, paypal, google-apps-script, terminal, expression

I'm having issues using a sed expression to get the data I would like. I've research it a bit, and tried a small tutorial but I could use some help. I feel that I can't use any

The closest I've come to a similar thread was "[How do i print word after regex but not a similar word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672139/how-do-i-print-word-after-regex-but-not-a-similar-word)".

I'm trying to parse through this to get information:

```
<table cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" border=""0""><tr><td>Product<br>Total: 9.99 CAD<br></td></tr><tr><td><br /> <table cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" border=""0"" style=""font-size:10px;""><tr><td colspan=""2""><b style=""color:#777; font size:12px;"">==Payer Info==</b></td></tr><tr><td width=""70""><b style=""color:#777"">First Name</b> </td><td>Greg</td></tr><tr><td><b style=""color:#777"">Last Name</b> </td><td>Allan</td></tr><tr><td><b style=""color:#777"">E-Mail</b></td><td>gregoryallan@me.com</td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
```

Ideally from this I'd like to get the persons first name. I have to make an expression that follows up until the `>` before the first name and then grab that variable.

```
$ sed -n 's/^.*[Payer Info] -- grab name and stop when you hit </td>
```

I've been misleading because I implied I was doing it in terminal. Which was my first goal. But now I need to use this RegEx in a Google Apps Script. I assumed that it would be similar - and it is not. Very sorry for all those who I misled.

Comment: Nice job on your first question.  Welcome to StackOverflow. :)

Comment: Does your HTML really have doubled-quotes delimiting the parameters? In general, you'd find it easier to process HTML using a parsers, rather than regex because HTML is too irregular to use a "regular" expression. Do you have any other language experience, such as Perl, Python or Ruby? They can all make short work of this without relying on regex. You can probably get away with a regex for this example because your search is simple but I doubt that answer would work for a real world situation.

Comment: Yes, in all cases it does have the double-qoutes from what I can tell. I do have some experience in Python - but limited as I took it as a course a while ago. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here I extracted you the name (Greg in your case):

```
sed 's_^.*First Name[^d]*d>[^>]*>\([A-Za-z]*\).*_\1_'
```

You can easily modify it to get other fields out.

Second name:

```
sed 's_^.*Last Name[^d]*d>[^>]*>\([A-Za-z]*\).*_\1_'
```

Email:

```
sed 's_^.*E-Mail[^d]*d>[^>]*>\([A-Za-z@.]*\).*_\1_'
```

Inside a script you can use something like:

NAME = $(echo $STRING | sed xxx )

where you replace xxx with the commands from sed.

There are many other possibilities to capture the output of a process inside a script.

Comment: Hi there, thanks so much! I'm now trying to incorporate it into a google script. I guess they don't play by the same rules. If I have a string, say 'code' myProduct = String(row[10]); 'code'. Then I declare the regular expression you gave me 'code' regExp = _^.*First Name[^d]*d>[^>]*>\([A-Za-z]*\).*_\1_; 'code' then use the command 'code' replVal = myProduct.replace(regexFormat, '$1'); 'code' What changes to the regular expression would need to be made to accept this? Thanks for your help - really going above and beyond.

Comment: Thanks for updating! These most certainly work for terminal :)

Answer (score 0):

This might work (assuming the format is always exactly like in your example):

```
sed -e 's/^.*First Name<\/b> <\/td><td>\([^<]*\).*$/\1/g' sed_sample
```